# How to generate a xml from a data.frame R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I would like to generate an xml file from a dataframe in R. 
Here is an example :

data.frame

```
x y z
1 2 'bla'
3 4 'blou'
5 7 'bli'
```

Xml result :

```
  <xml>
    <tuple x="1" y="2" z="bla" \>
    <tuple x="3" y="4" z="blou" \>
    <tuple x="5" y="7" z="bli" \>
 </xml>
```

Comment: have you tried the `XML` package?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this helps:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=3:5, z=c("foo", "bar", "baz"))
cat(paste("<xml>", paste('<tuple x="', d$x, '" y="', d$y, '" z="', d$z, '" \\>"', sep="", collapse="\n"), "</xml>", sep="\n"), "\n")
## <xml>
## <tuple x="1" y="3" z="foo" \>"
## <tuple x="2" y="4" z="bar" \>"
## <tuple x="3" y="5" z="baz" \>"
## </xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you're looking for using the `XML` package

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,5), y=c(2,4,7), z=c("bla", "blou", "bli"))
dat$z <- as.character(dat$z)
library(XML)
top <- newXMLNode("xml")
newXMLNode("tuple", attrs = dat[1,], parent = top)
newXMLNode("tuple", attrs = dat[2,], parent = top)
newXMLNode("tuple", attrs = dat[3,], parent = top)
top
```

Gives the output:

```
<xml>
 <tuple x="1" y="2" z="bla"/>
 <tuple x="3" y="4" z="blou"/>
 <tuple x="5" y="7" z="bli"/>
</xml>
```